# WSDoAllSender class replacement in wss4j-1.6.10?

Tags: wss4j, usernametoken

I have a WSDD what works well with wssj4-1.5.12. It looks like this:

```
<deployment xmlns="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/providers/java">
    <transport name="http" pivot="java:org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender"/>
    <globalConfiguration >
        <requestFlow >
            <handler type="java:org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllSender" >
                <parameter name="action" value="UsernameToken"/>
                <parameter name="passwordType" value="PasswordText"/>
                <parameter name="passwordCallbackClass" value="my.domain.Callback"/>
             </handler>
         </requestFlow >
    </globalConfiguration >
</deployment>
```

However, after switching to wss4j-1.6.10, I'm getting an ClassNotFoundException:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllSender
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
...
```

It does seem that WSDoAllSender is no longer in the wss4j-1.6.4 API. However, I cannot seem to find its replacement. Does wss4j still supports UsernameToken for SOAP connection? What's the replacement class for WSDoAllSender?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi @user1477923, I have the same problem. Please let me know If you found solution for this.